# Using grid.history in jqgrid to track search

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the grid.history plugin to achieve back button friendliness in jqGrid as detailed here: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/07/16/38612/.

The url changes on sort changes, paging, and other various events. However, it does not change when searching using the toolbar search. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, this feature was not implemented by default in grid.history.js .

You can still achieve this by customizing the grid property getting and setting in grid.history.js by replacing the implementation of `$jgrid.[get|set]PropertyValue` as stated in the [author's documentation](https://github.com/CraigStuntz/jqGrid/wiki/documentation).